# Need suggestion hot to move urllib2.install_opener() to a different class

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a code at the top of my program that looks like this:

```
cj=cookielib.CookieJar()
#Process Hadlers
opener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
#install opener, now all the calls to urllib2.urlopen use this opener
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
opener.addheaders=[
                    ('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (BlackBerry; U; BlackBerry 9850; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.11+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.0.115 Mobile Safari/534.11+'),
                   # ('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'),
                    ('Accept-Language', 'en-gb,en;q=0.5'),
                    ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate'),
                    ('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7'),
                    ('Keep-Alive', '115'),
                    ('Connection', 'keep-alive'),
                    ('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0'),
                    ('Referer', 'http://yahoo.com'),
                ]
```

So now I want to move this code to a different class, because I don't want to copy  and paste the code across my program. 
As far as I understand `urllib2.install_opener(opener)` add all the headers, cookies and so on to the `urllib2` when I call `urlopen()`.
Want to move it to some class but don't really know what this code supposed to return. Plus if I move it to the `__init__` method, it won't work, because **init** does not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have this code in a module named `urlhandler.py` and use the `opener` that you have defined above. `from urlhandler import opener` that should work. The code initializes the opener with all the appropriate handlers for it urllib2 to accept requests.

With this, you will be using `opener` to open the request object and get the response back

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.yoururl.com')
res = opener.open(req)
```

Comment: does it mean that I will need to use 'opener' instead of 'urllib2.urlopen()'?

Comment: Yes, opener has the open method where you can send the request object and get the response back.